# Parsing URL Only Using XPATH In C#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the following code:

```
 foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/@href[contains(., '/something/')]"))
             {
                 var content = link.OuterHtml;
                 // Then do something else
             }
```

`content` is equal to something like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.somelink.com">Happy Camper</a>
```

I would like `content` to equal just the URL portion of the HTML, so just this:

```
http://www.somelink.com
```

What would I need to change in my code to produce this desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just use:

```
var content = link.Attributes["href"].Value
```

Easy enough!